# Access element in default content after switching to iframe in WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am practicing with Webdriver in running basic tests, and this specific test is to send an email through Gmail and then assert that it's been received.

I'm using the new version of Gmail where the compose email button pops up a window asynchronously (see picture). To access the body of the email to type a message, I have to select the iframe, but then I am unable to switch out and access the "Send" button element.

There are no other noticeable frames which hold the "Send" button, and using driver.switch_to_default_content() doesn't do anything either. I've included a snippet of the code below.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("to").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("to").send_keys("toemailaddy@gmail.com")
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
subj = ("TEST - " + localtime)
print(subj)
driver.find_element_by_name("subjectbox").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("subjectbox").send_keys(subj)
body = ("TEST")
bodyFrame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='Ap']//iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(bodyFrame)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@role='textbox']").send_keys(body)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div[@role='button' and contains(text(), 'Send')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Inbox (1)").click()
```

I can get the message to send by using `ActionChains send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys,ENTER).perform()`, but would like to figure out how to access the "Send" button to click on it for the sake of my sanity :)

[image: gmailEmail]

Comment: I simply must point out here that as far as using web applications for learning WebDriver goes, Gmail is a spectacularly [poor choice](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/8jR6Fw5ndxU/7peVDuzkNN4J)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for elements which have different id every test run is to parse page source with regexp in order to extract the id. Maybe it is not most efficient solution but it works.

```
import re
pattern = "div id=\"(:\w+)\".*Send</div>"
xpath = ""
matchObj = re.search(pattern,driver.page_source)
if(type(matchObj)!=None):
    matchTuple = matchObj.groups()
    if(len(matchTuple)>0):
        xpath = "//*[@id=\"" + matchTuple[0] + "\"]"
print("SEND button xpath = " + xpath)
```